# UIImageView height change

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

I have textview (UITextView) and imageview (UIImageView) which is created in code side.

I am adding my text inside textview and then putting this textview inside imageview. Everything working correctly but when I use the long text then my imageview is not looking perfect.

In my first text 'Test data' with image is correct. But in second text my imageview arrow is going to down.

[image]

I want to see it in above instead of below like below image. How can I do it?

[image]

In my code first I am calculating the imageview height, width and coordinates and then

```
self.myImageView.image = UIImage(named: "greenOne")!.stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth(15, topCapHeight: 14)

self.myImageView.frame = CGRectMake(xValue, yValue, widthValue, heightValue)
self.myImageView.autoresizingMask = textView.autoresizingMask
```

PS:This is my imageview. I am always using this image. Just changing the height of this image.

[image]

Comment: Is the "greenOne" image the little arrow that is moving (does not appear to be so)? If not, can you post the code for where you generate and place the little side arrow?

Comment: @Ike10 I updated the question and added my image. I am always using this image. Just giving the heightValue.